# Long-term v lifelong

Tags: word-choice, differences, word-usage

Should I say "It's been a ***long-term*** dream of mine *to do sth*"
or "It's been a ***lifelong*** dream of mine *to do sth*"

Comment: Either is grammtical: we don't know which is more accurate in your case.

Answer (score 1):

**Long-term** or **short-term** is rather associated with *goals*, *plans*, *objectives* etc. and not with dreams. For dreams the word '**lifelong**' is much more suitable. Hence you should choose

> It's been a **lifelong** dream of mine to do...

You could refer to this n-gram from Google which compares occurrences of 'long-term goal', 'long-term dream', and 'lifelong dream'.

[image: n-gram comparing the phrases 'long-term goal', 'lifelong dream' and 'long-term dream']